# Apps Script suddenly stopped working due to TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror, undefined

A few months back a developer helped me out with pulling data from an API and storing this data in a Google Sheets file. Unfortunately this script has stopped working and the developer has moved on to other projects.

[This is the exact error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFmIC.png)

From the error I'm guessing the problem is in line 51 of the code. This line is part of a for-loop and is written as follows:

```
arrayProjectManagerName.push([jsonObject.data[i].project_manager.name])
```

The API documentation can be found [here](https://developer.simplicate.com/explore#!/Projects/get_projects_project). Could it be that project_manager.name contains null values and the script is therefore unable to write the data to the sheet? If so, I've tried replacing this line with:

```
if(jsonObject.data[i].project_manager.name === undefined {
arrayProjectManagerName.push([""])
}else{
arrayProjectManagerName.push([jsonObject.data[i].project_manager.name])
}
```

But unfortunately this breaks the entire script, not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here however.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Error messages should be included as text, not as images. Before posting a question, please spend some time searching for helpful content from this site. If you still need to post a question, include a brief summary of the most relevant posts and descrive why didn't help you or what is not clear about them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to the actual value inside "name" but to the parent object itself.

The field or property "project_manager" does not exist here:

```
jsonObject.data[i]
```

So, if you want to add proper handling logic it should be something like this:

```
    if(jsonObject.data[i] !== undefined 
&& 'project_manager' in jsonObject.data[i]) {
     arrayProjectManagerName.push([jsonObject.data[i].project_manager.name])
    
        }else{
          arrayProjectManagerName.push([""])
        }
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please, accept the answer so that others can see the response in the future. Thanks.